# Persisting data on ActionLink click MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home")` to currently pass back to "Home" when clicked. However, is it possible to get the page to perform a post on itself (i.e. Hit its post event in the controller) when the action link is clicked.

I basically need a method of navigating to a page, but first submitting all the current pages data into the model.

*Note*: Forgot to add that the `ActionLink` is inside a partialView on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AjaxHelper` method `ActionLink()` to submit a `POST` of the current page.  And then for your `HttpPost` action method in your controller, just do a redirect to `Home`.

Something like this:

**Your View**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me", "SubmitMe", "Current", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" })
```

**Your Controller**

```
public class CurrentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitMe(SomeModel someModel)
    {
        // do what you have to do here
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing though, I don't know how to make ActionLInk do a post, it just redirects/refreshes. Currently my navigation for other persistence is done in my controller in the httpPost as you mentioned.

Comment: @RawryLions ActionLink cannot do post, unless you use jQuery to override this behavior.

Comment: @RawryLions Sorry, typo.  I meant you need to use the `AjaxHelper.ActionLink()`.  That way you *can* cause a `POST`.

Comment: @Huske You cannot with `HtmlHelper`, but you can with `AjaxHelper`.

Comment: @Shark I agree, but my assumption regarding this question is that it is about `HtmlHelper` and not `AjaxHelper`. Good point! :-)

Comment: I used an idea similar to this as my current way of handling navigation postbacks on forms does this. I just created a custom type of link which uses the "value" to determine which form to goto next :)

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your form using javascript (i suggest jQuery) and redirect after.
What you can do too is to submit the form and use `RedirectToAction()` in your `[HttpPost]` decorated Actionmethod.

#### jQuery Sample

```
$(function() {
    $("#YourButton").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.post("YourUrlToPostTo", $("#yourForm").serialize(), function() {
         // success, redirect now
       });
     });
});
```

Comment: Can you do `$(whatever).parent().find(blah).submit()` into the parent view in MVC3? My actionlinks are inside a partial.

Comment: You can use the current action in your partial too. But i need more information to provide a better sample.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use action link in this manner. What you could do is to use jQuery to create JSON object or to stringify the contents of the form and then call .ajax() method by setting method to POST.

Your jQuery code could look like this:

```
$('#yourActionLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var yourValues = $("form").serialize();
    $.post($(this).attr("href"), yourValues, function() {
        alert("Data saved.");
    });
});
```

And that should be something like that.